# Prevent reCaptcha multiple image selections

Tags: recaptcha

I'm using Google reCaptcha for validation purposes on a client website. Today I've got a complaint/change-request from them, regarding the multiple image selection (Select 2 beers, wines, cakes etc.) validation of reCaptcha. My client thinks it's inappropriate to having their customers choose from alcoholic beverages because of socio-cultural standing of their customer base.

Long story short; is there a way to customize Google reCaptcha to only show number/letter based validation when "I'm not a robot" option fails.

Comment: Did you guys solve this, did u get rid of image selction and keep only tick mark?

Comment: nope still the same,

Comment: Is this still impossible to do?

Comment: There is now "invisble reCaptcha" and v3. Do these help? https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3

Answer (score 5):

I think I found a solution.
The [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq) contains information about a fallback mechanism for environments that do not support the reCaptcha checkbox widget.

By appending the parameter **fallback=true** you can explicitly use the fallback.

I haven't had any beer or wine reCaptchas yet since I've been using the fallback. 
(But still cake, sushi or road-sign reCaptchas)

Try the following:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?fallback=true'></script>
```

**EDIT:**
But the usability of the fallback widget is just horrible..

Comment: The problem is that you have force enabled that recaptcha picture selection, how to get rid of it? No clue for now...