# Way to skip reCAPTCHA images challenge

Tags: recaptcha

I am implementing reCAPTCHA on one of my websites and I have successfully implemented it. It is working fine. Sometime the reCAPTCHA gets completed only by clicking the "I'm not a Robot" but sometimes it shows the images grid to select the correct images and complete the captcha.

I was just wondering if this possible or not. Can we disable the images selection challenge so the reCAPTCHA can be completed only by clicking the "I'm not a Robot". What is the theory of Google for showing the images grid?

I have already read this : [Prevent reCaptcha multiple image selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746101/prevent-recaptcha-multiple-image-selections) but there is not enough information there.

Thanks!

I have included `recaptcha/api.js` below.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallbackAuto&render=explicit&hl=<?php echo $lang;?>" async defer >
```

My reCAPTCHA code is below:

```
    var onloadCallbackAuto = function() {
         /// do something....
    }
    var verifyCallback = function() {
         /// do something....
    }
    grecaptcha.render('gReCaptchaDiv', {
     'sitekey' : '<?php echo $siteKey;?>',
     'callback' : verifyCallback,
     'theme' : 'light'
    });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on **_why_** you want to be able to skip the image-selection challenge? Because it sounds like you want a robot to be able to pass the challenge, in which case you may as well disable reCAPTCHA - but if you have a different reason, then there may be other ways to solve your specific problem.

Comment: might as well put a checkbox and allow form submit only when the checkbox is clicked. your requirement makes no sense at the moment.

Comment: I am just checking if this is possible to skip the image challenge. It will be easier for my users to just check the "I'm Not Robot" checkbox and complete the process. If it is not possible i don't have any issues. Also I want to know when and how google decide to show the images challenge. It doesn't always show the images grid.

Comment: Does the newer API help? https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The new Google reCaptcha implements some sophisticated algorithms to decide if there is a real user or not. Some methods used are detection of request repeatedness (if there is a request repeating again and again in a small time period from one particular source), time counting (how long time passed since when the script was initialized), cursor events (like moving and clicking), scroll events, javascript common events triggering and XHR calls.

All these and many more methods, combine the invisible reCaptcha and in the case of the Checkbox reCaptcha, some of these detection methods get to trigger as well. If the algorithm detects something unusual for a human user, for example, clicking on the reCaptcha checkbox without the mousemove event to get triggered, then that will not evaluate to a human result and thus reCaptcha has to rely on something else to ensure that there is a human doing stuff and not a script bot.

The answer is that you cannot avoid it. If the basic reCaptcha method fails then it has to do something to provide protection.

Keep in mind that the users of your application will not see the images method very often like you do. I guess that you're doing some testing and trying the same things again and again after doing some code updates, thus you get the reCaptcha failing more often due to the repeatedness from the same source.

Comment: thank for clarifications. So we can not bypass the images challenge as it is part of the reCAPTCHA functionality and infact is correct to further verifying and confirm that it is a human being and not bot.

Comment: @elegant-user exactly. There is no point bypassing it, because there is a reason why it popups at the first place. Just remember that is less likely the users of your applications to get that images challenge like you do because you are doing lots of testing and thus you repeat the same requests again and again something that the final users won't do.

Comment: You are correct. I am doing lot of testing on my app and very often I am seeing images grid

Comment: During development this is turning out to be a nightmare. It is wasting my time as I'm testing things and making changes, etc. I can't sit here for 5 minutes selecting street signs, buses, cars. It's driving me crazy. They should have a bypass at least for testing purposes. This is completely ridiculous.

Comment: @emirhosseini why don't you just disable it for the development phase and then re-enable it when you're done writing your app/code? You know it works, there is no point having it enabled during development I think. If you are editing a live application, then you should consider having a development enviroment with source control. It's not right to edit production apps/code directly.

Comment: @ChristosLytras I'm not editing production directly. I made no mentions of production. During development locally I was trying to wire up reCAPTCHA for the first time and responding to its event and doing the verification POST back to Google, etc. so I had no choice but to go through the pain. Hope that makes sense. The thing in development itself was the wiring up of recaptcha and it kept showing me slide after slide of pictures to click on.

Comment: @emirhosseini There is a better way to use Google captcha in the development environment, without getting irritated with the repetitive image puzzles. You can use Recaptcha Global Keys for testing purpose. Please refer this link [link] (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha-what-should-i-do)

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't skip it.

I am surprised that no one pointed out why we get them. The image recaptcha is not only to detect that the user is not a bot. If you notice, they are always related to traffic, bridges, signs, store fronts and so on. Google uses this tool to train artificial neural networks , mainly for autonomous cars. This method is called supervised training.

In neural networks there are two types of training, supervised and unsupervised training. Supervised training is when you provide a mechanism of manually grading the performance of the network. So when you choose all those car pictures, the network is also attempting to do the same, you are basically grading the network's performance. The more input it gets, the more intelligent it becomes by adjusting the weights of each neuron in the network.

In unsupervised training the network has to make sense of whatever you are trying to teach without outside help. It is a lot less efficient but it still can be done.