# How do I force Google reCaptcha to show challenge images?

Tags: recaptcha

I'm trying to implement a reCaptcha on my site. Right now, I just it just asks me to click on the checkbox and I'm verified. I want it to present an image/text challenge every time instead.

This question has been asked a couple of times but there hasn't been a working solution. Most of the other questions I could find only ask how not to present a challenge to the user.

I know that it checks if you're a bot in other ways and only shows the challenges if the verification fails, but does it offer the option for developers to invoke the check manually?

Comment: Can you see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45856419/9871463 ?

Comment: @DinkoPehar that question is about how to skip the challenges and even the answer doesn't state whether you can manually invoke it or not.

Comment: Answer states there are multiple parameter that define whether it will show images or not. I used reCaptcha on one of my sites that I build, it only triggered "image grid" few times, a lot of time it just adds checkmark that you are not a robot. It internally decides are you bot or not to show images. EDIT: http://aukcije-online.herokuapp.com/register here is my site, spam a few times and check and it will pop up images